A $C^\ast$ algebra that has trivial $K_1$ group, but not all unitary operators in it are path-connected
Does there exists a $C^\ast$ algebra $A$ such that $K_1(A)=0$, but not all unitary operators in $A$ are connected by a continuous path?
If $K_1(A)=0$ and $U$ is a unitary operator in $A$, then $[U]=0$ and for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is a continuous path connecting $U\oplus 1_n$ and $1_{n+1}$. However, it doesn't seem that it would give a path between $U$ and $1$. Therefore, I suspect there should be some (hopefully easy) example.
Conversely, is there example where the unitary operators in $A$ are path-connected, but $K_1(A)$ is nontrivial?

In the case of unital abelian C$^\ast$-algebras, both of these questions have answers that are easily referenced (well, the latter counter-example just happens to be abelian). For the former, check out Rørdam's blue book, chapter 8.3. If $A = C(X)$ is a unital abelian C$^\ast$-algebra (i.e., $X$ is compact), then
$$K_1(A) = U(A)/U^0(A) \oplus \ker \det  = \pi^1(X) \oplus \ker \det$$
where $\det: K_1(A) \to U(A)/U^0(A)$ is the map $\det([u]_1) = [\det u]$ with $\det$ taking a matrix to the "usual" determinant defined for regular old matrices, except we are working over $A$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$. $\pi^1(X)$ denotes the "cohomotopy group".
So, in the unital abelian case, if $K_1(A) = 0$, then $U(A)/U^0(A)$ is zero as well. One would be hard pressed to find "easy" examples not coming from cummutative C*-algebras. This is because lots of simple C$^\ast$-algebras that people are interested in have the property of being "$K_1$-injective", i.e., $U(A)/U^0(A) \to K_1(A)$ is injective. In fact, it is often bijective -- for example, if $A$ is unital, simple and purely infinite, or if $A \simeq A \otimes_{\min} \mathcal{Z}$ where $\mathcal{Z}$ is the Jiang-Su algebra.
As for your converse, look at exercise 11.3 in the same book. One gets thats $U(C(S^n))$ is connected for all $n \geq 2$, but $K_1(C(S^n)) = \mathbb{Z}$ if $n$ is odd.
I'll also add that you can even find C$^\ast$-algebras with $U(A)/U^0(A)$ being non-abelian.

Thanks for the answer. Are there any C* algebras that are not K1 injective? It is clear from your answer that it must at least be non-commutative. It remains unclear whether my main question has a positive answer.

Sure, non K1 injective things exist. E.g., if $U(A)/U^0(A)$ is non-abelian, it wont inject into the abelian group $K_1(A)$.

That’s right thanks. Do you have in mind a concrete/standard example in which $U(A)/U^0(A)$ is non-abelian?

Yep, you can look at example 8.1.2(d) in Blackadar's K-theory book. Apparently its the case that $A = M_2 \otimes C(U(2) \times U(2))$, where $U(2)$ is the unitary group of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, yields an example.
